# minitest controller testing failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

I'm experiencing trouble to test controller with minitest. My problem just in the following case - when I'm attempting to delete record. Controller is just basic scaffold in namespace `admin`, but test is below:

```
require 'test_helper'

describe Admin::ProvidersController do

  let(:provider) { FactoryGirl.create(:provider) }

  it "gets index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil assigns(:providers)
  end

  it "gets new" do
    get :new
    assert_response :success
  end

  it "creates provider" do
    assert_difference('Provider.count') do
      post :create, provider: { description: 'Description', name: 'Name' }
    end

    assert_redirected_to admin_provider_path(assigns(:provider))
  end

  it "shows provider" do
    get :show, id: provider
    assert_response :success
  end

  it "gets edit" do
    get :edit, id: provider
    assert_response :success
  end

  it "updates provider" do
    put :update, id: provider, provider: { description: 'New description', name: 'New name' }
    assert_redirected_to admin_provider_path(assigns(:provider))
  end

  it "destroys provider" do
    assert_difference('Provider.count', -1, 'An Provider should be destroyed') do
      delete :destroy, id: provider
    end

    assert_redirected_to admin_providers_path
  end

end
```

on `rake test:controllers` I see:

```
Started

Admin::ProvidersController
  test_0001_gets index                                            PASS (0.12s)
  test_0002_gets new                                              PASS (0.17s)
  test_0003_creates provider                                      PASS (0.01s)
  test_0004_shows provider                                        PASS (0.04s)
  test_0005_gets edit                                             PASS (0.05s)
  test_0006_updates provider                                      PASS (0.01s)
0
0
  test_0007_destroys provider                                     FAIL (0.02s)
Minitest::Assertion:         An Provider should be destroyed.
        "Provider.count" didn't change by -1.
        Expected: -1
          Actual: 0
        /Users/alec/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@lorgnette/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/testing/assertions.rb:76:in `block in assert_difference'
        /Users/alec/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@lorgnette/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/testing/assertions.rb:73:in `each'
        /Users/alec/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@lorgnette/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/testing/assertions.rb:73:in `each_with_index'
        /Users/alec/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@lorgnette/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/testing/assertions.rb:73:in `assert_difference'
        /Users/alec/Documents/Projects/RubyApps/lorgnette/test/controllers/admin/providers_controller_test.rb:42:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'


Fabulous run in 0.43316s
7 tests, 11 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

in logs I see:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
Admin::ProvidersController: test_0007_destroys provider
-------------------------------------------------------
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "providers"
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "providers"
   (0.2ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "providers" ("created_at", "description", "name", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2014-05-30 23:06:43.102303"], ["description", "MyText"], ["name", "MyString"], ["updated_at", "2014-05-30 23:06:43.102303"]]
   (0.2ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
Processing by Admin::ProvidersController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"271"}
  Provider Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "providers".* FROM "providers"  WHERE "providers"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 271]]
   (0.2ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  SQL (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "providers" WHERE "providers"."id" = $1  [["id", 271]]
   (0.1ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
Redirected to http://test.host/admin/providers
Completed 302 Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "providers"
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "providers"
   (0.5ms)  ROLLBACK
```

What's wrong with delete test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because at the time you assert_difference provider count is zero, provider count is incremented when the "id: provider" is referenced, and then provider count is decremented by the destroy.  So it starts at zero and ends at zero.

Try this instead...

```
  it "destroys provider" do
    provider
    assert_difference('Provider.count', -1, 'An Provider should be destroyed') do
      delete :destroy, id: provider
    end
  end
```

That way the provider is instantiated before the assert_difference block.

Answer (score 2):

As Steve said, `provider` has not been created until you are calling the `delete` call. You can easily avoid that by using [`let!` instead of `let`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-6/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let).

```
let!(:provider) { FactoryGirl.create(:provider) }
```

Using `let!` will call the `FactoryGirl.create` *before* the test starts.

Comment: Good suggestion, although technically the question was in regards to Minitest. Minitest does not provide let! by default. However, I did create a gem that provides it and that would allow this suggestion to work for Minitest: https://github.com/kstevens715/minitest-bang